# Preloading an m3u8 video in HTML with <link rel="preload">

Tags: html, video, media, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm using the `<link rel="preload">` attribute to preload my video for faster playback.

But my video is an `.m3u8` file, which is a playlist file that links to several chunked `.ts` files.

In order to successfully preload my video, should I link to the playlist file

```
<link rel="preload" as="video" href="https://cdn.com/file.m3u8">
```

or

link to the source files like so:

```
<link rel="preload" as="video" href="https://cdn.com/file1.ts">
<link rel="preload" as="video" href="https://cdn.com/file2.ts">
<link rel="preload" as="video" href="https://cdn.com/file3.ts">
```

Comment: you should like to the m3u8, because you want the browser to determine at runtime what bandwidth the user can support to stream. if your m3u8 is correctly formed and indicated that it's a VOD file then some browsers will attempt to preload segments from a `<video preload="auto" src="...m3u8">`

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Answer so I can accept..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link to the m3u8 from a `<video>` tag, because you want the browser to determine at runtime what bandwidth the user can support to stream.

If your m3u8 is correctly formed and indicates that it's a VOD file (as opposed to a live stream) then some browsers will attempt to preload segments from a  - better to use their logic in most cases.